# Overleaf editor colors

Tags: color, editors

I'm afraid I pressed some unknown shortcut that caused my editor to not highlight parts of code anymore such as /section{} in a different color than the text. It has the same color for every character like this:[image]

I've tried changing the themes but I won't get the highlighting colors back. How do I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use the main menu button to open up the sidebar and scrolldown to see the editor theme

[image]

I believe that the setting shown above (editor theme textmate) is the default, but pick one you like.